# Polynomial With Imaginary Roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, factoring

Working on question 1 here
http://www.sosmath.com/cyberexam/precalc/EA2002/EA2002.html

Find a polynomial with integer coefficients that has the following zeros:  `-1/3, 2, 3+i`

Multiplying `(3x+1) (x-2) (x-3-i)` produces a polynomial with i scattered throughout the terms. Not the right answer.

Then I thought maybe the root `3+i` implied another root `3-i`.

That didn't produce the right answer either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: 'Then I thought maybe the root $3+i$ implied another root $3-i$'. You thought well. What did you do exactly to reach the conclusion that it didn't work?

Comment: You are in the right track. The complex roots always come as conjugated. Thus the equation will actually have 4 roots. Then you can rewrite into $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)=0$ form, and you will have your answer.

Comment: Is your next factor $x+3-i$ instead of $x-3+i$ perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: a polynomial with integer coefficients that has the root $3+i$ *must* have also the root $3-i$. However

$$
(3x+1) (x-2) (x-3-i)
$$

doesn't have the root $3-i$. How can you make from this a polynomial that has also the desired root?

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Expand%20%283x%2b1%29%28x-3-i%29%28x-3%2bi%29%28x-2%29) agrees with the solution on the page you link to $ (3x+1)(x-3-i)(x-3+i)(x-2)=3 x^4-23 x^3+58 x^2-38 x-20$